# Navigation Bar, Relative Links

Tags: php

i'm building a php cms style app for tracking of members characters, the projects coming along nicely, but I am wondering if there is a more efficient way of coding my navigation bar.

the bar is included in many different pages so relative links as standard will not work for obvious reasons, the way I have been getting around this is by

```
if (strstr($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'], "admin/char/")) {
$home = "../../index.php";
$logout = "../user/logout.php";
} else if (strstr($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'], "admin/user/")) {
```

etc.

so I have each combination of path that could be typed, and this solution works, and quite well, but since I am copying pasting code and making changes the chances of me missing something is increased, and with more links this chance is increased.

I am wondering if there a better way of achieving the same result with less code?

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: does anyone else have any other ways of doing this?

Comment: I keep a variable that knows per page on which level it is so it's easy to have relative links back to base.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to create a common configuration file (include in all your scripts) where you define a constant (e.g. BASE_URL = 'http://localhost/your_site/').

Then, change all your links with ABSOLUTE values instead, using the BASE_URL constant defined in the configuration file.

In the end you will have something like:

```
$home = BASE_URL . 'index.php';
```

which will always be a valid link.

At deployment, you will need to change the  configuration file and set `BASE_URL` as your new domain (e.g. `www.mysite.com`).

Comment: yes the point is this is open code for other website administrators to use, so the actual url of the host will vary.

Comment: You would have different menu links depending on the user role, but that will not have anything to do with the BASE_URL which remains constant. If the menu for an administrator is different, they you should have a different block based on the user type, not on the `SCRIPT_FILENAME` and those links would still start/use the same `BASE_URL` : `BASE_URL.'admin/logout.php'`

Comment: no you mentioned at deployment I would need to change the base url implying a manual change, I would require something that will work on any domain, automatically without the admin requiring to type in this address.

Comment: You could set `BASE_URL = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` which will work on almost all cases, but not when you have your scripts in a folder (e.g. `http://localhost/project1/`). I don't think it is such a big effort to change the file manually, since you would also have to change some other settings during deployment (e.g. database connectivity, error reporting ?)

Comment: your missing the point, I dont want the people who use my script to have to edit this file by hand as it could lead to misconfiguration.

Answer (score 0):

the previous advice, while not exactly answering my question did give me the idea to use a variable called $BASE_URL. from here I have use sytax such as.

```
if (strstr($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'], "admin/index.php")) {
$BASE_URL = substr($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'], 0, -15)
} else if (strstr($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'], "index.php")) {
$BASE_URL = substr($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'], 0, -9)
}
```

I have repeated this for multiple paths, while it does take up a fair bit of space, all I have to do when links are broken from one page is add that pages address and corresponding length, which is much easier.

I have included this code in my header.php file thus making the variable accessable throughout the site also.